# Alinhar uma imagem colocada como "list-style-image" com o texto do <li>

Tags: html5, css3

Adicionei uma imagem junto à lista através do "list-style-image" e o resultado ficou desalinhado (imagem 1). Como posso fazer para alinhar essa imagem com os textos da li assim como da imagem 1, ou seja, no centro do texto.

```css
.topicos li {
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #7B7A7A;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-left: 20px;

}

ul {
    list-style-image: url('arrow.png');
    padding-left: 56px;
}
```

```html
<ul class = 'topicos'>
                        <li>Entender e priorizar os processos e necessidades da sua empresa e como a Cizino pode ajudar;</li>
                        <li>Mostrar na prática como nossa plataforma de gestão funciona;</li>
                        <li>Tirar toda e qualquer dúvida sobre nossos produtos;</li>
                        <li>Discutir planos, preços, projetos e tudo que for necessidade da sua empresa.</li>
                    </ul>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acho que memo tentando estiliza o `::marker {}` não vai rolar, melhor vc usar a imagem como um pseudo elemento da li, ou usar a img como background da li, e controla o tamanho e posição com os atributos de background